# Update and Change WordPress URLs in database with REGEXP

Tags: php, mysql, regex, wordpress

I want to change several hundred URLs to the graphics inside the posts. URLs are links to images that are on an inactive imagehost. I had backup and I loading them into a new imagehost, but I have a problem with replacement, because old links have variable, random length.

For example:
`hostname.org/image/ciiidl/file_name.jpeg`

Where "ciiidl" is generate random

I wrote a command in SQL, but unfortunately did not replace URLs:
`UPDATE wp_posts SET post_content = REPLACE (post_content, 'https://old_hostname.org/image/[^a-zA-Z0-9]/','https://new_hostname.com/Img/')`

I need to use REGEXP, but I do not know how to combine with REPLACE.

Comment: Please show what results you want.

Comment: Old: hostname.org/image/ciiidl/car.jpg New: hostname.com/Img/car.jpg

Comment: MariaDB, but not MySQL, has `REGEXP_REPLACE()`.

Comment: Yes, I know about it. Oracle Database has `REGEXP_REPLACE()` too.

Answer (score 0):

I think you just need:

```
UPDATE wp_posts
    SET post_content = concat(substring_index(post_content, '/image', 1),
                              '/Img/',
                              substring_index(post_content, '/', -1)
                             )
    WHERE post_content LIKE '%/image/%';
```

Answer (score 0):

Previously I made this changes, but when the link it was static:

`UPDATE wp_posts SET post_content= REPLACE(post_content, 'https://old_hostname.org/image/','https://new_hostname.com/img/')`

I just changed the beginning of the url. The file name has been unchanged.